# Work out co-prime of two numbers in java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I have two BigIntegers holding prime numbers.

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.probablePrime(16, new Random());
BigInteger b = BigInteger.probablePrime(16, new Random());
BigInteger c;
```

How would I find the co-prime of these two BigIntegers and store it in c;

Comment: AFAIK, co-primality is a specific relationship between two numbers. What does this have to do with a third number? By the way, there is no `b`.

Comment: that was a typo error, a and b are two random numbers generated and the co-prime to be store in c?

Comment: There is no *the co-prime*, so please explain what you mean. `a` and `b` are co-prime if they are unequal.

Comment: I think i might have not explained this correctly. But what im asking is how would you work the co-prime of two numbers if the two numbers are prime numbers.

Comment: @prolog12345 For RSA you don't need to find a number that's co-prime to the modulus or its prime factors, but co-prime to phi(n)=(p-1)*(q-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Co-primality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) of integers a and b refers to the question of whether the gcd(a,b) = 1 or not. Java's BigInteger class provides the [`gcd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#gcd(java.math.BigInteger)) method to compute this:

```
BigInteger c = a.gcd(b); // or equivalently b.gcd(a).
```